# Automapper flattening embedded objects

Tags: automapper, flatten

I have a class (many more fields than defined below, but you get the basic idea):

```
public class Embedded
{
    public int Field1{get;set;}
}
public class Source
{
    public int Field2{get;set;}
    public Embedded Embedded{get;set;}
}

public class Destination
{
    public int Field1{get;set;}
    public int Field2{get;set;}
}
```

The normal approach would be:

```
Mapper.Initialise(cfg=>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>(dest=>dest.Field1, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Embedded.Field1));
}
```

My Embedded object has many fields (and I have multiple embedded objects) and they will map by convention to the fields in the Destination object.

I need something like the functionality provided by IncludeBase<> but to be able to specify which field should be used to use as the src.

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I found Map<,>(s,d) and AfterMap:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg=>{
    cfg.CreateMap<Embedded, Destination>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
        .AfterMap((s,d) {
            Mapper.Map(s.Embedded, d);
        }
});

var src = new Source{
    Embedded = new Embedded();
}
var dest = Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(src);
```